# How to implement Animation built by using physics-based APIs

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm new in android. I use Spring Animation. 
I want the image to fall slowly

```
public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
    float y = 0;
    do {
        view1.setTranslationY(y);
        SpringAnimation animY = new SpringAnimation(view1,
                DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y, 0);
        //animY.setStartVelocity(10);
        animY.getSpring().setStiffness(SpringForce.STIFFNESS_VERY_LOW);
        animY.getSpring().setDampingRatio(SpringForce.DAMPING_RATIO_LOW_BOUNCY);
        animY.start();
        y+=1;
        Log.d("TAG", "getTranslationX= " + String.valueOf(view1.getTranslationX()) + " getTranslationY = " + String.valueOf(view1.getTranslationY()));
    } while (y < height);
```

Comment: code example please

Answer (score 0):

```
private VelocityTracker velocityTracker;

spinAnimation = (View) findViewById(R.id.spinAnimation);
        velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();

  spinAnimation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                SpringAnimation animY = new SpringAnimation(spinAnimation, SpringAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y, 0);
                animY.getSpring().setStiffness(STIFFNESS_LOW);
                animY.getSpring().setDampingRatio(DAMPING_RATIO_LOW_BOUNCY);
                animY.setStartVelocity(velocityTracker.getXVelocity());
              animY.animateToFinalPosition(100);
                animY.start();
            }
        });
```